# display UserValue in plmxml schema using XSLT

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

Hi i have the following code and i want to display the UserValue from the ProductRevision which matches the instancedRef in the Occurrence. the schema is plmxml...

```
<ProductRevision id="id279" name="Intermediate Shaft" accessRefs="#id17" subType="M3HI_MPTRevision" masterRef="#id284" revision="A" source="unset">
<ApplicationRef version="gCVFl6cKY1F1YB" application="Teamcenter" label="Q_VFl6cKY1F1YB"></ApplicationRef>
<UserData id="id280">
<UserValue value="11111" title="m3hi_Order_No"></UserValue></UserData>
<AssociatedForm id="id283" role="IMAN_master_form" formRef="#id281"></AssociatedForm></ProductRevision>
```

I am trying to get the value of UserValue using the below XSLT

```
<xsl:variable name="mptRevID" select="substring-after(/plm:PLMXML/plm:ProductView/plm:Occurrence[@id=$mptId]/@instancedRef, '#')"/>
<xsl:variable name="RevTag" select="/plm:PLMXML/plm:ProductRevision[@id=$mptRevID]"/> 
<xsl:variable name="Ord" select="$mptRevTag/plm:UserData/plm:UserValue/@value"/>
```

When i execute the above it is giving me a blank in the output.

Please let me know the mistake i am doing in my code or how to access the UserData and UserValue from the xml.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Second Variable name is `mptRevTag`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the special XSLT processor for PLMXML.
http://plmski.webnode.com/plmxml-xslt-processor/
The processor determines the "ref-id" automatically. You do not need to determine the ID.

Comment: Can you explain where the OP's problem originates and how your answer will help solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you've got here 2 problems:

1. Typo: you use "$mptRevTag" instead of "$RevTag" in your select for the variable "Ord"
2. Xpath: in the PLMXML structure (at least the ones I know), the ProductRevision elements are not directly located under the root node, but the XPath expression should look like following: /PLMXML/ProductDef/InstanceGraph/ProductRevision

Furthermore, I would certainly also filter the UserValue thanks to the 'title', as all attributes from Teamcenter are exported with this element.

Regards, Loic